# The Big Facebook Share Buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-like

I'm wondering how I can implement the big facebook share buttons that I see around.  Is there a tutorial somewhere, or perhaps a wordpress plugin?  Thats what I'm using.

[Here is an example](http://www.upworthy.com/this-kid-wants-to-fall-in-love-with-a-woman-just-like-his-mom?c=fea) of what I'm talking about:

### Normal

[image: Preview]

### Hover state

[image: Preview engaged]

Comment: Looking at that page, it looks like the styles are coming largely from  [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) along with some custom styles. You should be able to right-click, inspect and get the styles you need to create a similar look.

Answer (score 0):

Tuts+ has a tutorial for something similar. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-awesome-practical-css3-buttons/

But basically. It's a css3 gradient, that disapears on hover. Also to create the double border effect it seems he used nested elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR TITLE&p[url]=YOUR URL&p[images][0]=YOUR IMAGE URL" class="facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
```

If you want it in a popup window etc. as most do, please ask.

```
.facebook{
background: url(NONE HOVER FACEBOOK BUTTON IMAGE) no-repeat;
display:block;
width: WIDTH OF IMAGE;
height: HEIGHT OF IMAGE;
text-indent: -999em;
}
.facebook:hover{
background-image: url(HOVERSTATE FACEBOOK BUTTON IMAGE);
}
```